# Doctrine2 Entity Manager cannot find Custom Repository Class in namespace

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

I have Silex setup with Doctrine2 ORM. I am trying to build a pagination class that I can use with my entities. I am well aware of the existing pagination classes that exist within Doctrine2 but because this project is for my school research I am trying to create this component myself.

Below is the fatal error I get when accessing this page:

> Fatal error: Class 'PlayGround\Model\Helper\UserRepository' not found in D:\web\playground-solutions\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 689

I have defined an interface called **PaginateableInterface** with two methods count and paginate. I went on to define a custom **EntityRepository** class that extends ***Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository***. Below is my custom EntityRepository.

```
<?php

 namespace PlayGround\Service\Doctrine;

 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository as ParentEntityRepository;

 class EntityRepository extends ParentEntityRepository{

   public function count(){

      $em       = $this->getEntityManager();

      $builder  = $em->createQueryBuilder();
      /**
      * ToDo: @entity
      *
      * Still need to find a better way of getting entity class name.
      */
      $entity   = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class(__CLASS__))->getName();

      //Dynamically get a count of records on any entity we happen to call this on.
      $builder->select($builder->expr()->count('e'))
       ->from($entity, 'e');

      $query   = $builder->getQuery();

      //Try-Catch block ommitted
      return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
  }
```

```
 <?php

   namespace PlayGround\Model\Helper;

   use PlayGround\Service\Doctrine\EntityRepository as CustomRepository;
   use PlayGround\Contract\PaginateableInterface as IPaginate;

   class UserRepository extends CustomRepository  implements IPaginate
   {
    }
```

In my understanding this should suffice as the count and paginate methods are sitting within the custom repository.

Inside my Paginator class I call the entity I want to paginate as shown below:

```
<?php

  //Paginator class
  $model = $this->getModel($model);
  //Count should be inherited from CustomRepository aliased object.
  $totalRecords = $model->count();
```

Below is another pierce of meet with regards to this where I add an annotation to my model to point it to the repository class it is suppose to use.

```
<?php
  namespace Application\Model\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Application\Model\Entity\UserGroup;


 /**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PlayGround\Model\Helper\UserRepository")
 */
 class User{ /* Rest of the code goes here... */ }
```

Given all this setup what could I have missed in getting this to work? I have even ran two commands on my doctrine console but that didn't help either.

```
Luyanda.Siko@ZACT-PC301 MINGW64 /d/web/playground-solutions
$ php app/Console/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:metadata
  Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
  Successfully deleted cache entries.

Luyanda.Siko@ZACT-PC301 MINGW64 /d/web/playground-solutions
$ php app/Console/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:query
  Clearing ALL Query cache entries
  Successfully deleted cache entries.
```

EDIT:

Below is my file structure found in D:\web\playground-solutions.

[image]

Comment: What are the paths you use to store the classes in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare twice  `@ORM\Entity`. Once with the `repositoryClass` and once without. Remove the one without:

```
@ORM\Entity
```

and leave this:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PlayGround\Model\Helper\UserRepository")
```

`@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` should be declared without parentheses `()`...

Also make sure that the `EntityRepository` is in the correct namespace and the corresponding folder:

your namespace is `PlayGround\Model\Helper\UserRepository` meaning the file should be in folder `PlayGround\Model\Helper` and the class file name should be `UserRepository.php`.

Fix and check that and if it still doesn't work leave a comment.

### UPDATE:

Your `UserRepository` is in the wrong module. Is now in `app` should be in `PlayGround`

Comment: Thanks @Wilt. I have just applied your suggestions and I still get the same   fatal error. I have included my file structure in the EDIT section of my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LuyandaSiko Read my update... You are having a namespace issue.

Comment: Thanks @Witt for bringing my brains back to life. I resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

The file should be in:

```
src/PlayGround/Model/Helper/UserRepository.php
```

It's all about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this has really consumed my thought process. All I was doing was pointing to an incorrect namespace as pointed out by @Witt.

I changed my annotation entry in the User entity and the error went away.

```
 <?php
   /** @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Model\Helper\UserRepository") */
```

Thanks you guys.